# Android Google Geofencing transition jumps even device is not moving

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I have developed a Geofencing App, which is working mostly proper. But I have also users saying me, that the app is reporting repeatable entering and exiting of the zone even the device is not moving!

The app uses the latest Google Geofencing API with the transition types GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER and GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT with expiration NEVER_EXPIRE and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION on. The users configured also a large radius with 2000 meters with no success. The locations are set to high accuracy.

But the transitions is jumping from exit to enter, even the device is on the table in the house and not moving.

How can I improve this in the app?

Comment: This may be a limitation of the location technology. GPS does not work well in buildings.

Comment: The user set the location to high accuracy, which means it uses not only GPS, but also GSM and WiFi. His other devices in the same place are working well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google geofences mainly use network points, which rely on wifi and cell towers, and are prone to varying levels of accuracy.  This causes a lot of location point "jumps" that the geofence registers as enter and exit events.  One way to prevent this, is to make a gps call on a transition event, to verify that the user did indeed leave.  If the user left, send the notification, if not, reset the geofence with `INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT` set in `GeofencingRequest`.

Comment: Good idea, but not possible in that case, because I use expiration NEVER_EXPIRE. So I would have then an **exit** fence and the fence **enter/exit**, which already reported the exit and then soon will report the enter. The user and the actions behind will be confused.

Comment: In your BroadcastReciever or IntentService, once you've verified that the event was in fact false (using GPS), grab the [geofences](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingEvent.html#getTriggeringGeofences()) that caused the violation, and modify them as necessary (use [Geofence.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder) to recreate using the same requestID), and re-add them.  If you use the same requestID for the geofence, it doesn't make a new one, it just updates it.

Comment: OK, I understand. I will try to implement it.

Comment: Just wondering if either of you ever managed to find a solution to this issue as I am currently stuck with this issue also.

Comment: Even after you followed the instructions given in the answer?

Comment: The only gps coordinates I get on the transition event are the ones which the user has jumped to, not the true location of the device. @PabloBaxter

Comment: The points given by the geofence are typically network points, and not very accurate. What you want to do is when you get the geofence event, take a GPS point to verify the event. If you didn't really exit, just reset the geofence, otherwise, perform whatever action you wanted to do.