# Android - Geofence trigger when lost gps

Tags: android, google-api, gps, android-geofence

i used the google simple code to "Creating and Monitoring Geofences" and every thing works fine but i have one problem that when the device lost gps signal for second the trigger event will count this as exit , and when signal back will count as enter

even it's still inside Geofence ,i guess i can't avoid this situation 
so did any one know if this behavior can be suppressed?

also An additional questions, i read alot in stackoverflow geofence problems that using a BroadcastReceiver better than Service to receive the transitions
right now i use service to receive and it's work fine , Is it necessary change it to BroadcastReceiver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Google Geofence relying on bad network location points at times.  I have a potential solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617007/android-google-geofencing-transition-jumps-even-device-is-not-moving).  It's not 100%, but it does help suppress the geofence jumps.

As for the second part of your question, I don't know if you mean the IntentService or just a Service.  If it is a Service, I would recommend using an IntentService or BroadcastReceiver.  IntentServices are mostly used for performing tasks on a background thread, where BroadcastReceivers are meant to restart the process (if it wasn't force killed by the user), and perform a quick task to handle the intent.  Both of those are self contained, and destroy themselves right after the task is done.  But to answer your question, no, you don't *have* to use a BroadcastReceiver, but it is better practice to do so.

Comment: thx for your reply really help, and yes i was mean IntentServices
but there part in your answer i didn't understand well "is to make a gps call on a transition event" what you mean by gps call ?

Comment: When you get the false exit, use LocationManager to call for a GPS point.  If you get a point outside the geofence, perform your exit code block.  If your point is still in the geofence, just reset the geofence to the same center point, but make the geofence bigger by 25m.  Make sure you have a max size for your geofence, since you don't want something that is bigger than what you really want.

Comment: i see thanks 
but is make geofence bigger really necessary ? cuz my geofence have 200 radius now and i don't want to make it more bigger

Comment: If it is about that big, no.  It was if you had something small, like 50m.

Comment: i see , one last question, when update the Geofence is count as entered or will send the enter notification again ?

Comment: You can set the transition type when you re-add the geofence to GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT.  Now when the geofence is re-updated, it should only report when you exit, not when you enter.